# Why use Django's collectstatic instead of just serving the files directly from your static directory?

Tags: django

From the Django Docs:

> Deployment django.contrib.staticfiles provides a convenience
>   management command for gathering static files in a single directory so
>   you can serve them easily.
>
> Set the STATIC_ROOT setting to the directory from which you’d like to
>   serve these files, for example:
>
> ```
> STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/static/"
> ```
>
> Run the collectstatic management command:
>
> ```
> $ python manage.py collectstatic
> ```
>
> This will copy all files from your
>   static folders into the STATIC_ROOT directory.
>
> Use a web server of your choice to serve the files. Deploying static
>   files covers some common deployment strategies for static files.

What's the purpose of copying the files, why not just serve them from the directory they live in within the app?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why not just serve your `static` directory? You might use more than one app, and some of your apps may not be under your control. Before the `staticfiles` app existed, you then had to either manually copy the static files for all apps to a common directory, upload them to your CDN, or symlink them to the document root of your web server.

The staticfiles app established a convention: put static files for each app under a `static` directory and let Django do the work for you.

Comment: Maybe I've just never used an app that needed that (besides admin). So in my case when I don't need that is there anything wrong with serving static files directly from the static directory?

Comment: If you want to stick to best practices, use the staticfiles app. I'd only directly serve static files for really small projects, and even then it is better to "build a habit" of doing it right

Comment: IIRC, they were in different places for each app, and you had to follow the installation instructions for your app for static files to work, e.g. make static files at path X available at URL Y

Answer (score 12):

The `STATIC_ROOT` can be on a different machine than the application, so copying your static files to the static root means that you can serve your static files from a different server (CDN FTW!) which you wouldn't be able to do if those files where only located within their respective app directories.

Comment: This is the best answer; people shouldn't recommend using staticfiles/collectstatic for its own sake; this is what it is meant for.

Comment: Do you mean STATIC_ROOT or STATIC_URL? I would assume the later, because if it's a different server, then the files would be served using a URL. correct me if I am wrong please.